# I have to find out the domain from a given list of URLs.But the URLs don't follow a format.What is the best method to do this?

Tags: python, sql, teradata-sql-assistant

Some examples are :

`amazon from https://www.amazon.com/cart/233452876/confirm`

`tophatter from com.tophatter.tophatter.payments//:success?paymentId`

`google from www.google.com/search?`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the first string between two periods.  If so:

```
select replace(regexp_extract(url, '[.][^.]+[.]'), '.', '')
```

Comment: The period is a special character in a RegExp so you need to escape them: `'\.[^.]+\.'` also if this is Teradata database the other function is named `oreplace`.

Comment: @Fred . . . Thank you!

Comment: Some of the URLs are also like `https://example.org` where I need to extract abc and also `https://pay.depop.com/` where depop should be extracted

Comment: @laya . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.